# Django .create() for each item in queryset? Like: Reporter.objects.all().article_set.create(...)

Tags: django, django-models, orm, django-queryset, crud

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/,

Taking Django's Reporter/Article as a comparable example for my real problem, i need to create one new article for each reporter in my queryset.

My approach now is as follows:

```
reporters = Reporter.objects.filter(...)
for reporter in reporters:
    article = Article()
    article.reporter = reporter
    ...
    article.save()
```

The problem is that i have 25k "reporters", so it takes too long to process the request and raises timeout.

I wonder if there is a better method for that, sort of like:

```
Reporter.objects.filter(...).article_set.create(...)
```

Comment: I ended up saving a list:
    `reporter_values = Reporter.objects.filter(...).values_list('id')`
Then using list comprehension i built every single Article in python:
    `articles = [Article(reporter_id=value[0], ...) for value in reporter_values]`
And finished everything with a: 
    `Article.objects.bulk_create(articles)`
Which solved the problem down to under a second, but still, if there is a better way to do that, i would love to know.

Answer (score -1):

You should try doing something like:

```
reporters = Reporter.objects.filter(...)
for reporter in reporters:
    Article.objects.create(reporter=reporter, ....)
```

That should be more efficient but not sure if it'll solve your problem. You might need to do it batches if not.